# Excel Array Function to Sum a number of COUNTIF statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having difficulty phrasing this intelligently, but I'll try the long way -- I need a function that assigns a 1 or 0 depending on whether the row has an "x" in one of four previous columns and then sums all those assigned values.

In other words, imagine the following formula is in E2 and autofills down for any given number of rows.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:D2, "x")>=1, 1, 0))
```

I want to write an array function in F2 that would do the equivalent of summing all the values in column E (but don't reference column E).

Sum of ...

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:D2, "x")>=1, 1, 0))
=IF(COUNTIF(A3:D3, "x")>=1, 1, 0))
=IF(COUNTIF(A4:D4, "x")>=1, 1, 0))
=IF(COUNTIF(A5:D5, "x")>=1, 1, 0))
...for all of column A through D
```

Sample Data:

```
A         B         C         D 
20-Sep    20-Sep    21-Sep    21-Sep            
x         x 
          x         x
          x 
x           
                              x 
          x     
x           
x                   x   
x
```

The formula should return the value 9. There are 9 rows that have an "x" between the columns A and D.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the results you expect?  I'm confused by the "sums all those assigned values" part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this out:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(--(A2:D5="x"),{1;1;1;1})>0))
```

Commit normally (array entry will neither help nor hurt). If your production range is wider than 4 columns expand the {1;1;1;1} array.

Also works:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(N(A2:D5="x"),{1;1;1;1})>0))
```

Comment: nicely one! and this is fast :D Actually, you don't need `SumProduct`? A simple `Sum` will do i think.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: @andyholaday I am able to use this formula up to 8 columns wide until Excel runs out of resources on my computer. I can certainly work around this, but just wanted to ask if you had any idea how to apply this formula to columns A2:P2 (16 columns wide).

Comment: @l42 and yes you are correct. A simple `Sum` works just fine.

Comment: @bfs1990, I just tested to 48 column x 30-odd rows and it works the same with no hiccups. Awkward? Yes. But no errors here. not sure why the resource problem emerges for you.

Comment: @andyholaday Hmm ... Is it because I set the formula to `=SUM(N(MMULT(N(A:D="x"),{1;1;1;1})>0))`? Will Excel use less resources if I limit it to A2:D500? I got the same resource program using my personal computer and work computer. I'm running Windows (Bootcamp) on my rMBP with Intel i7 2.3 GHz and 16GB RAM.

Comment: @bfs1990 wish I knew why this is happening for you. When I try using `A:D` the formula takes a second or two to calculate (even if there's only data in 6 rows) whereas a 500 row range is instantaneous. Either way, it runs. (Excel 2007 32 bit running on Windows 7 enterprise, 64 bit, 2.4 GHz AMD Opteron quad core + 16GB RAM)